# How could i simplify this code without using the same code, variable outside scope doesn't work with "start,end,days"

Tags: jquery

Hello i am writing some code for shower coins to be calculated and also the number of nights calculated from 2 dates (from and to). That works, everything works but i thought by my self that this code can be better without duplicating same code inside functions. I tried to get the date variables outside of scope but it doesn't work. Hope someone can give me an answer with a minified version of mine. More explanation **below**.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  //Count day's for input howManyNights
  $(".datepickerChange").on("change",function(){
        var start = $('#from1').datepicker('getDate');
        var end   = $('#to1').datepicker('getDate');
        var days   = (end - start)/1000/60/60/24;

        $("#howManyNights").val(days);
  });

//Calculate shower coins
  $('select.countForShowerCoins').on('change', function() {
    let sum = 0
    $('select.countForShowerCoins').each(function() {
      sum += Number($(this).val());
    })

    var start = $('#from1').datepicker('getDate');
    var end   = $('#to1').datepicker('getDate');
    var days   = (end - start)/1000/60/60/24;
//Repeat for i dont know how to use same variables in other function
$("#showerCoins").val(sum * 3 * days +" muntjes, 3 per persoon per dag");

$(".datepickerChange").on("change",function(){
      var start = $('#from1').datepicker('getDate');
      var end   = $('#to1').datepicker('getDate');
      var days   = (end - start)/1000/60/60/24;

  $("#showerCoins").val(sum * 3 * days +" muntjes, 3 per persoon per dag");


});


  });

});
```

I am using the first function block for the day's to be calculated inside an input field before i touch the counting inputs for shower coints.

The second function blck is for calculating the shower coins with counting the days(dates) to multiply it with. The last function block is for if the user wants to change the date and then the dates get calculated inside `#ShowerCoins.val`

So i hope someone can simplify this without using duplicates, i don't know how to do it.

Thank you very much for your time!

Comment: Can you post an example of your html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We dont have your html to test it, but something along these lines would work. The idea being that we refactor each logical step in the process into a distinct function and then call those functions as needed:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.datepickerChange, select.countForShowerCoins').on('change', function() {
        setCoins();
    });

    // loop over the selects an sum up their values
    function getSum() {
        let sum = 0;
        $('select.countForShowerCoins').each(function() {
            sum += Number($(this).val());
        });
        return sum;
    }

    function getDays() {
        let start = $('#from1').datepicker('getDate'),
            end   = $('#to1').datepicker('getDate'),
            days  = (end - start) / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24;
        $('#howManyNights').val(days);
        return days;
    }

    function setCoins() {
        $('#showerCoins').val(getSum() * 3 * getDays() + ' muntjes, 3 per person per day');
    }

    // call once automatically to set initial values
    setCoins();
});
```

Comment: Works perfect, thanks for your time. I will learn myself to put code in functions as you did(if needed). Thank you for your time sir.